# pandoc converting reStructuredText to Markdown fails on headings

Tags: markdown, pandoc, restructuredtext

I try to convert a reStructuredText into Markdown using `pandoc`. But from my understanding `pandoc` does fail on the headings.

Here is an `test.rst` file

```
Heading 1
=========
one

Heading 2
---------
two

Heading 3
+++++++++
three
```

Now I use this command to convert it

```
pandoc test.rst -f rst -t markdown --output test.md
```

The result is

```
Heading 1
=========

one

Heading 2
---------

two

### Heading 3
```

This is IMHO not correct. What I would expect is this output

```
# Heading 1

one

## Heading 2

two

### Heading 3
```

I assume that `pandoc` is right and just my assumption are wrong. Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing are so-called “setext-style headings”, while those starting with a hash `#` are “ATX-style headings”. Older pandoc versions used setext-style as the default, but will switch to ATX-style if the `--atx-headers` command line option is given.

Newer pandoc versions (2.11.2 and later) use ATX-style headings as default, and can switch to setext-style via `--markdown-headings=setext`, so updating to the latest version would help as well.